# ImportError: No module named testing with z3c.form.testing imports

Tags: plone, zope, z3c.form

Trying to run z3c.form.testing based code on Plone 4.1 and getting this exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/xxx/DATA/projects/SVN_xxx_eggs/Products.xxxPatient/Products/xxxPatient/tests/test_views.py", line 13, in <module>
   from z3c.form.testing import TestRequest
 File "/home/xxx/DATA/projects/xxx_FOLDER/xxx_414/buildout-cache/eggs/z3c.form-2.5.1-py2.6.egg/z3c/form/testing.py", line 23, in <module>
   from zope.app.testing import setup
ImportError: No module named testing
```

Do z3c.form needs special support or pindowns with Plone 4.1 to run unit tests? There might be need to refer testing modules in setup.py, but are there examples how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not a version issue here. It seems that your testrunner can't find the entire package `zope.app.testing` so you just need to specify the `extra_requires` keyword "test" (take a look here for [z3c.form's extras_require](http://svn.zope.org/z3c.form/trunk/setup.py?view=markup)) in your buildout like this:

```
[buildout]
eggs +=
    z3c.form [test]
test-packages =
    z3c.form

[test]
recipe = zc.recipe.testrunner
defaults = ['--auto-color', '--auto-progress']
eggs =
    ${buildout:eggs}
    ${buildout:test-packages}
```